# how to use custom language values in joomla module parameters?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I want to call the parameters of the backend module from the language file of another component.
this code only changes php values in frontend ​​but does not change the values ​​of xml parameters in backend .

```
JFactory::getLanguage()->load('com_mylanguage');
```

I want to change this lable in backend module : "MYLANG_LABLE"

```
<field name="title" type="list" default="" required="true" label="MYLANG_LABLE" description=""></field>
```

Comment: Please post your Joomla questions on Joomla Stack Exchange.

Comment: could you try for JFactory::getLanguage ()->load ('com_yourextension', JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR);